# Measure theory. Equivalence of two sets

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space. Suppose X is a real random variable, and suppose $X_n, n \ge 1$ are a sequence of step random variables such that $X_n(\omega) \rightarrow X(\omega)$. Then, I need to show that it follows from

$$\sup_{k>0} \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}\{\omega: X_n(\omega) <x-\frac{1}{k}\} = \{\omega: X(w)<x\}$$.

I have two questions. First, I don't understand what the sup part is doing there and why do we need to take the sup and not just look at $X_n(w) < x$. Secondly, aren't the omegas on the LHS the ones such that $X_n(\omega) \le x$ for all but a finite number of n so that if $X_n(\omega)=x$, we don't have equality between the two sets?

Edit: $\sup_{k>0} A_k := \cup A_k$.

Comment: How do you define $\sup_kA_k$?

Comment: Good question. This is from a book. What I think it means here is  an infinite intersection where k runs from 1 to infinity.

Comment: But now that I just wrote it, it might mean an infinite union here..

Comment: This is important so put it in an edit if you find it

Comment: Thanks Snoop. It is indeed a union and I solved it. I will write the solution soon incase someone might find it useful in the future.